# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'DTO.DataModel'

Tags: c#, linq

```
 public ObservableCollection<DataModel> DataList { get; set; }
 public DataModel SelectedItem { get; set; }
```

When I do  as below:

```
SelectedItem = DataList[0];  // its working fine.
```

But I need to get the distinct like

```
SelectedItem = DataList.Select(x => x.InnNum).Distinct();
```

But this shows error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type  'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'DTO.DataModel'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)"
```

Can somebody help me on this?

How to solve it. 
How can i convert IEnumerable to model type before asssigning it to SelectedItem ?

Comment: [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb348436(v=vs.100).aspx) is still giving you a collection of results (even though there may only be 1 item in the collection.

Comment: The two things are completely different `DataList[0]` is the first element in `DataList` a single `DataModel`, whereas `DataList.Select(x => x.InnNum).Distinct()` is a distinct list of `InnNum`objects from `DataList`.

Answer (score 0):

`DataList.Select(x => x.InnNum).Distinct()` would give you an `IEnumerable` of `string` objects.

Which you are trying to set to `SelectedItem` which of the Type `DataModel`. Hence the error.

Comment: I know the error reason. i am asking abt how to solve it.pls help to solve it.

Comment: i am trying to assign an Ienumerable string to a Model type. what i asked is the other solution. How can i get the Distinct InnNum ad how can i assign to SelectedItem ?

Comment: Yes! you can either assign Model type to SelectedItem or you will have to convert your IEnumerable<string> to model type before asssigning it to SelectedItem